# Reset Increment Variable for Sample ID

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I am new to Power Automate flows. I was tasked to create a Unique Sample ID based on parameters from a SharePoint list, when an entry is created. I have created a SharePoint list, whose function is to hold the increment variable, which is my counter. The current flow increments this counter variable, whenever an item is created in the main SharePoint.

The Sample ID is suppose to reset every year based on the logged date of the incident, which is different than the stored date. For example, 2020SPI1, 2020SPI2, and 2021SPI1, 2021SPI2. I am trying to get an idea on how to do this.

I do not want a flow that resets the counter every year, since the stored date of the entry can be different from the date that the incident occurred.

Answer (score 0):

In Order to make your format like 2020SPI1

Step 1: Initialize a vairable named as PatternId

Step 2: Set Variable. You can use string concat function in value of variable as following

```
 concat(formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyy'),'SPI',items('Counter')
```

First argument here will produce current year: 2020.
Second argument is a static string: SPI.
Third your counter value from the list holding incremented number.

Then finally you can use PatternId to updated the id in your list column. Hope this can help you out.